# Splitting Text Box Contents VB2008

Tags: vb.net

I am splitting the contents of one text box into others in VB, I am using a space as where the split occurs. As the original text can have a different number of spaces but I know the maximum is 8, is there a way for VB to ignore the extra split commands instead of showing as errors?

Thanks.

Code:

```
Dim strA1 As String = TrackABox.Text
Dim splitA1 As String() = strA1.Split(" ")
A1.Text = splitA1(0).ToString()
A2.Text = splitA1(1).ToString()
A3.Text = splitA1(2).ToString()
A4.Text = splitA1(3).ToString()
A5.Text = splitA1(4).ToString()
A6.Text = splitA1(5).ToString()
A7.Text = splitA1(6).ToString()
A8.Text = splitA1(7).ToString()
```

In some cases, Split 6 and 7 may not be required.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare an array of your textboxes, then use a loop for just the number of items present in the splitting result

```
Dim strA1 As String = TrackABox.Text
Dim splitA1 As String() = strA1.Split(" ")
Dim ctrlText As TextBox() = new TextBox(){A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7,A8}
For x as Integer = 0 to splitA1.Length - 1
    ctrlText(x).Text = splitA1(x)
Next
```

In this way the looping over the `splitA1` array is used to extract the string at the current loop position and assign it at the corresponding Text property of the array of TextBoxes.

Consider also that there is no check about the length of the `splitA1` array because you say that it could have 8 or less elements and the textbox array is always big enough to contain the splitted substrings. You could add a check about this or (as explained in the other answer) use the Split function overload that limits the resulting array to at 8 elements. `Split(" ", 8)`

Comment: I'm getting a "'Text' is not a member of 'System.Array' message just now, the rest of it is working fine.

Comment: Do I need to declare that 's' as something? (You may have guessed, I am an amateur at this!)

Comment: Again another error of mine, That's happen when you write on the fly without the possibility to test. Fixed again the answer

Answer (score 1):

The [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method already takes a parameter to limit the count of items

```
Public Function Split ( _
   separator As Char(), _
   count As Integer _
) As String()


If (splitA1.Length >= 8) Then A8.Text = splitA1(7)
```

Comment: I was getting an error when I tried this with something that could only be split 7 times, I assumed this was because there was nothing to split?

Comment: You got an error using the `count` parameter greater than the number of separators? You really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude empty/whitespaced items when splitting the string, just using the proper `Split` method overload.

```
Dim StringParts As String() =
    "This     is a             too white-spaced string".
    Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For Each Part As String In StringParts
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("""{0}""", Part))
Next Part
```

Output:

```
"This"
"is"
"a"
"too"
"white-spaced"
"string"
```